# How to clean cache of a project after building it?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on a `Julia` language project. After doing some coding: let's suppose now I am preparing to test my project (means the project is building correctly or not) or it completely errors free.
So, I just put the below command in my ubuntu terminal:

```
julia make.jl
```

After running the above command, I got some output that tells what errors I am getting. According to that, I solve them and I submit my Pull request then `CI` tests my PR, and all tests are successfully passed.
But after fixing the errors, I again run `julia make.jl` in my ubuntu terminal, it shows same errors which I had got previously(even after making changes in my code). So it is preventing me to check locally that all tests are passing or not and because of it, I have to create a commit and PR, again and again, to check that all are working properly or not. So, how can I get rid of this problem?
And, I am using the `ubuntu 20.04` terminal in my `wsl`.

Comment: Would [this SE site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julia) be a useful resource for you to ask your question and giver a wider scope for an answer?

Comment: @24601 It can be but I thought this problem is related to the `ubuntu` terminal. So I put it here